# How to create a new user in office365 from powerapps

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm creating a registration app where I want to create user id on office 365 for the registering person.

I used AzureAD connector to create user in Azure AD but when I viewed that created user on office 365 , sign in was blocked for him.

Any other method to add new user with sign in unblocked?any flow?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide more info for the technical side? i.e. show us some screenshots of where you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

> **If you are admin, to unblock Sign-In for the existing user,**

***Go to Microsoft 365 portal -> Active Users -> Open settings of the User -> Unblock Sign-in -> de-select Block this user from signing in -> Save changes.***

Otherwise, you can **select and de-select Block this user from signing** in to change user sign-in status.

[image]

If it won’t fix the issue, perform a **password reset** for the user.

**For reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/access-management/account-blocked-error-when-sign-in

> If you are **creating new user in Azure Active Directory**, you have
> the option to disable Block Sign-In option.

[image]

If not, admin may need to assign **license**, please refer: [Create User in Azure AD](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-user-in-azure-ad-and-assign-office-365-licenses-using-power-automate/)